# How to use chrome.notifications.create() in my webpage

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to use chrome rich notifications Api in my webpage via Jquery.

Requirement is:

- I want to send desktop notifications to the user using my website.

Currently i am not able to get any output from my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     if(chrome.notifications){
      chrome_notification_create();
     }
    });
    
    
    var chrome_notification_create = function() {
     
     // This is just for later usage not considered now
     
     var options = {
       type : "basic",
       title : "User Update",
       message: "Dear User XYZ U have recieved an update",
       iconUrl: "outsourcing.png"
     }
     
     chrome.notifications.create(
       'id1',
       {
        type:'basic',
        iconUrl:chrome.runtime.getURL("img/dan_logo2_128_padded.png"),
        title : "User Update",
        message: "Dear User XYZ U have recieved an update",
        priority:1,
        buttons:[{
         title:'call'
          },
          {
           title:'send mail'
          }
        ],
        isClickable: true
        
       },
       function() {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
       }
      );
    }
```

The error which i am receiving is : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined`

I have also found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification).

which is fulfilling my requirement. BUT my senior wants me to use Chrome API only(As the mozilla one says This is an experimental technology).

So please try to pinpoint the mistake in my code if any. Or any technical detail i might be skipping.

Comment: @Hidden Fisher thanks for the edit now it's cleaner. I am new at this so please excuse me for long format.

Comment: I encountered another issue, now its in firefox. The desktop notification is closing automatically due to some bug. Is there any way to avoid this bug in fire fox. Please suggest if there is any javascript way or any plugin etc.

Comment: Hello  everyone... Do you know the solution to this problem. Its urgent

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably forgot to add "notifications" to your permissions in

> manifest.json

It should be something like this

> { "permissions": ["notifications", ...] }

Also, you should try to reload your extension.